# How to play audio in Windows phone from uri that was returned from BingTranslationService?

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, audio, translate

I am trying to have my Windows app read text outloud. I am using the BingTranslationService to do so but I'm not sure how to play the audio from the result that I get from the service. I tried using the SoundEffect class but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

```
BingTranslateServiceReference.LanguageServiceClient client = new BingTranslateServiceReference.LanguageServiceClient();
  client.SpeakAsync(appID, name, "en", "audio/wav");

void client_OnSpeakCompleted(object sender, BingTranslateServiceReference.SpeakCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
    SoundEffect se;
    SoundEffectInstance soundEffectInstance;
    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(e.Result);
    req.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(ReqCB), req); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, apologies for the self-promotion but I have some sample code here 
[ms-translator-api-text-to-speech](http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/ms-translator-api-text-to-speech-wp7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can play this either using a MediaElement or using a SoundEffect

There's a good blog post and full app that uses the MediaElement at http://sigurdsnorteland.wordpress.com/2010/11/20/loud-tweets-a-twitter-to-speak-wp7-app-source-code-included/ - also on codeplex

I've used SoundEffect  in Iron7 (and a few other apps) - see some sample code in https://github.com/slodge/main/blob/master/Hosts/Silverlight/Iron7/Views/IronPage.xaml.cs and https://github.com/slodge/main/blob/master/Hosts/Silverlight/Iron7/Common/AudioPlayer.cs
- basically the code is:

```
var soundEffect = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect.FromStream(stream)
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
soundEffect.Play();
```

---

For these short sound clips (max 100 characters to that Bing speech service) I recommend the SoundEffect route - it's lighter than the MediaElement.